# Unable to define record pointer

Tags: delphi, pointers, inno-setup, record

I'm trying to implement a record pointer in Inno Setup (Unicode) to match a Delphi DLL's specifications...

```
type
  PUnzipFile = ^TUnzipFile;
  TUnzipFile = record
    Caption: WideString;
    Src: WideString;
    Dest: WideString;
    Status: Integer;
    Size: Integer;
    ErrCode: Integer;
    ErrMsg: WideString;
  end;
  TUnzipFiles = array of PUnzipFile;

function UnzipFiles(var Files: TUnzipFiles; const Silent: Bool): Bool;
  external 'UnzipFiles@files:Unzipper.dll stdcall';
```

The problem is that the compiler fails on the line `PUnzipFile = ^TUnzipFile;` because apparently Inno Setup doesn't support pointers as Delphi does. This record pointer works perfect when implemented in Delphi...

```
function UnzipFiles(var Files: TUnzipFiles; const Silent: Bool): Bool; stdcall;
  external 'Unzipper.dll';
```

How can I work with this DLL if Inno Setup doesn't support record pointers?

Comment: For the record, I changed the entire approach at the project, as I have control over the said DLL. Now, Inno Setup calls a procedure `UnzipperAddFile` with necessary parameters, and then `UnzipperGo` to initiate the actual process, with also `UnzipperInit` and `UnzipperUnInit` handled.

Comment: I'd still like to know how I could accomplish this using these record pointers

Comment: Have you tried to move the pointer declaration after the record declaration?

Comment: The design of the interface is wrong. Who is going to allocate the records?

Comment: I don't understand why you would pass an array of pointers rather than an array of records. The former requires way more work.

Comment: @David As I mentioned, I changed the whole approach so now it doesn't pass pointers. However, I'd still like to know how to accomplish this, which LU RD points out code order

Comment: What you still have not addressed is the semantics. Who allocates the memory? Is it the caller or the callee? Since you used `var` the only logical conclusion is that the records are allocated by the callee and pointers to those records passed back to the caller. I am prepared to bet that's not what you want. You really ought to explain why you want to pass by var an array of pointers. That's a really horrid data type.

Comment: @David Yes, the client allocates each array member, as well as unallocates when done. The DLL passes back result to the caller. But again, I completely changed the structure to not even use these record pointers because indeed it was a poor design.

Comment: What you should have done is passed by var an array of `TUnzipFile`. Arrays of pointers are usually an indication of poor design, and should set your spider sense on tingle mode. I've sometimes had to use arrays of pointers when I want to cope with a record whose size can vary from version to version. But that's a rare scenario.

Comment: @LURD I did try this but with no luck.

Comment: Inno's script does not support pointers at all.  The closest that you can get to them is to pass a single value or array by reference using `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for pointers.
Inno Setup Pascal Script does not support pointers.

The statement:

`function UnzipFiles(var Files: TUnzipFiles; const Silent: BOOL): BOOL;
  external 'UnzipFiles@files:Unzipper.dll stdcall';`

Passes `Files` as a var parameter, which means that what's really passed is a pointer to `TUnzipFiles`. There is no need to make `TUnzipFiles` array of pointers.
Just make it a normal array and everything will work.

The solution is to just use an array of the record in question:

```
TUnzipFiles = array of TUnzipFile;
```

Now it will work.

Because a var parameter passes a pointer internally your call will not be any slower (or faster).
That's the beauty of Delphi. It hides the complexity of pointers in almost all cases where you'd need it in C.
All objects references and var parameters are really pointers, but you needn't worry about that.